# How can I create three child processes by a child process?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, fork

I want to create three child processes from a child process of the main process (P0). So something like -->

```
P0 -> P1 ->P2  
             ->P3
             ->P4
```

However, whenever I run it I get (for the processes P2,P3,P4) the ppid of the main process (ppid = 1).

I am using fork() system call in order to create the children and the implementation of the program is in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int i, pid1, pid2;
    pid1 = fork();
    printf("Pid1 pid -> %d ppid -> %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
    if(pid1 != 0)
    {
        pid2 = fork();
        printf("Pid2 pid -> %d ppid -> %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
        if(pid2 == 0)
        {
            for(i=2; i<5; i++)
            {
                //if(fork()==0)
                //{
                    printf("Child %d pid -> %d Parent -> %d\n",i+1,getpid(),getppid());
                //}
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("Pid2 father process \n");
        }  
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Pid1 child process\n");

    }
}
```

Comment: you do not want to "create *three* child processes from a child process of the main process" but to create a child process having itself *one* child process having itself two child processes

Comment: Thank you for responding, yes i would like P1 to have the ppid of the P0 and the rest of the processes to have the ppid of the P1

Comment: Warning you start P2 while you are in P0 rather than in P1. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Warning, in

```
pid1 = fork();
printf("Pid1 pid -> %d ppid -> %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
```

the *printf* is done both in P0 and P1, this is unclear at all, you have first to check *pid1* before to print where you are.

Warning, in

> ```
> pid1 = fork();
> ...
> if(pid1 != 0)
> {
>    pid2 = fork();
> ```

you supposed to be in P1 when you *fork* again, but you are still in P0 because *pid1* is not 0

It is also recommended to check *fork* success (return value is not -1), and wait for the child(ren) termination rather than to exit the parent process before

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    int pid1 = fork();

    if (pid1 == -1)
      perror("cannot fork p1");
    else if(pid1 != 0)
    {
      int pid2;

      printf("In P1, Pid1 pid -> %d ppid -> %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

      pid2 = fork();

      if (pid2 == -1)
        perror("cannot fork p2");
      else if (pid2 == 0) {
        int pid3[2];
        int i;

        printf("in P2, Pid2 pid -> %d ppid -> %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

        for (i = 0; i != 2; ++i) {
          pid3[i] = fork();
          if (pid3[i] == -1)
            perror("cannot fork P2 child");
          else if (pid3[i] == 0) {
            printf("in Child %d pid -> %d Parent -> %d\n",i+1,getpid(),getppid());
            return 0;
          }
          else
            puts("in p2");
        }
        waitpid(pid3[0], 0, 0); /* erroned if fork failed, whatever */
        waitpid(pid3[1], 0, 0); /* erroned if fork failed, whatever */
      }
      else {
        puts("still in p1");
        waitpid(pid2, 0, 0);
      }
    }
    else 
    {
      puts("in P0");
      waitpid(pid1, 0, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % ./a.out
In P1, Pid1 pid -> 68995 ppid -> 54669
in P0
still in p1
in P2, Pid2 pid -> 68997 ppid -> 68995
in p2
Child 1 pid -> 68998 Parent -> 68997
in p2
Child 2 pid -> 68999 Parent -> 68997
/tmp %
```

Note the written pid are wrong,  from the manual of *getppid* :

> then a call to getpid() in the child  will  return the  wrong  value (to be precise: it will return the PID of the parent process)

Answer (score 0):

You want something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int i, pid1, pid2;

    pid1 = fork();
    printf("Pid1 pid -> %d ppid -> %d\n",getpid(),getppid());

    // parent
    if(pid1 != 0)
    {
        pid2 = fork();
        printf("Pid2 pid -> %d ppid -> %d\n",getpid(),getppid());

        if(pid2 == 0)
        {
            for(i=2; i<5; i++)
            {
                if(fork()==0)
                {
                    printf("Child %d pid -> %d Parent -> %d\n",i+1,getpid(),getppid());
                    // some functionality here
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
            exit(0);
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("Pid2 father process \n");
        }  
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Pid1 child process\n");

    }
}
```

Giving the following output in my machine:

```
Pid1 pid -> 17764 ppid -> 32242
Pid1 pid -> 17765 ppid -> 17764
Pid1 child process
Pid2 pid -> 17764 ppid -> 32242
Pid2 father process
Pid2 pid -> 17766 ppid -> 17764
Child 3 pid -> 17767 Parent -> 17766
Child 4 pid -> 17768 Parent -> 17766
Child 5 pid -> 17769 Parent -> 17766
```

Thus, with the following hierarchy:

```
Parent (pid: 17764) -> C1 (17765) -> C2 -> 17666
                                          C3-> 17767
                                          C4-> 17768
                                          C5-> 17769
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, yes that's it, I don't know what's wrong but my machine displays a completely different output :(

Comment: That's because you are dealing with processes. Don't forget that the scheduler decides when and where each process executes and that's dependent on several factors (current load, priorities, ...)